# Does VMWare Workstation/Player allow multiple kernel images?

Tags: vmware

I am planning to use VMWare workstation for installing linux. But my use case is to have multiple kernel versions as part of development requirement.

Does VMWare allow use of this?

I mean will GRUB or loader prompt me for loading of kernel of my choice the way which it will do on actual system ?

Thanks, kedar

Comment: Since one of the FAQ-allowed categories is "software tools commonly used by programmers" and VMWare (and its brethren, despite their clear inferiority `:-)` ) are pretty darn useful for testing/development environments, I disagree with the close vote. Feel free to ignore my opinion if you wish, I just thought I'd get it out there in case anyone was wondering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will allow this. Linux does not care if it is running in a VM or on real hardware. As far as Linux knows (except for the VMWare tools, of course), it *is* running on real hardware.

The VM "disk" is just a file on the host file system so can be set up independently of that host file system, including boot loaders and such.

Comment: Thanks for your confirmation!

Answer (score 0):

Vmware workstation mimics a true hardware installation very well, almost everything you can do in a physical box you can do in a virtual machine. It's not perfect but it is pretty close to it. I use a 2 physical machine setup to mimic a 10 machine domain lab.  The ability to save snapshots or to pause a machine makes it better than a physical machine in some respects.

It is a great tool and one that I recommend for anyone learning IT